# Transferring data between Google Docs and Basecamp

Tags: google-drive, basecamp

How do I transfer data and files between Basecamp and Google Docs applications?

Basecamp is a web-based project-management tool. Google Docs is a free, web-based word processor, spreadsheet, slide show, form, and data storage service offered by Google.

Is there an application I can use to transfer my documents and data between the two services?

Answer (score 1):

Try to use [cloudHQ](http://cloudHQ.net) service. [cloudHQ](http://cloudHQ.net) service provides the following features:

- copy and move files and folders between Google Docs, Basecamp, and SugarSync (or Dropbox) directly from Google Docs interface
- browse and view Basecamp project attachments and SugarSync (or Dropbox) files directly from a Google Docs interface
- automatic backup of multiple Google Docs accounts and Basecamp projects to SugarSync storage (or Dropbox storage)
- continuous two-way synchronization of multiple Google Docs accounts, Basecamp projects, and SugarSync storage (or Dropbox storage)